# Using localStorage to get my Save Button to Work

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

In my program you can drag and drop players into different teams. If you were to drag 'Player A' into the 'Team D' column. How can I manipulate localStorage, or any other function, to save which team I assigned the players to when I click the 'Save' button at the bottom?

Note: The code doesn't work in the Snippet, it only works if you copy it and save it as a HTML file and then run it on your Browser.

```js
/* VARIABLES YOU COULD MODIFY */
var boxSizeArray = [13,13,13,13,13,13]; // Array indicating how many items there is rooom for in the right column ULs

var arrow_offsetX = -5; // Offset X - position of small arrow
var arrow_offsetY = 0; // Offset Y - position of small arrow

var arrow_offsetX_firefox = -6; // Firefox - offset X small arrow
var arrow_offsetY_firefox = -13; // Firefox - offset Y small arrow

var verticalSpaceBetweenListItems = 3; // Pixels space between one <li> and next
          // Same value or higher as margin bottom in CSS for #dhtmlgoodies_dragDropContainer ul li,#dragContent li


var indicateDestionationByUseOfArrow = false; // Display arrow to indicate where object will be dropped(false = use rectangle)

var cloneSourceItems = false; // Items picked from main container will be cloned(i.e. "copy" instead of "cut").
var cloneAllowDuplicates = true; // Allow multiple instances of an item inside a small box(example: drag Student 1 to team A twice

/* END VARIABLES YOU COULD MODIFY */

var dragDropTopContainer = false;
var dragTimer = -1;
var dragContentObj = false;
var contentToBeDragged = false; // Reference to dragged <li>
var contentToBeDragged_src = false; // Reference to parent of <li> before drag started
var contentToBeDragged_next = false;  // Reference to next sibling of <li> to be dragged
var destinationObj = false; // Reference to <UL> or <LI> where element is dropped.
var dragDropIndicator = false; // Reference to small arrow indicating where items will be dropped
var ulPositionArray = new Array();
var mouseoverObj = false; // Reference to highlighted DIV

var MSIE = navigator.userAgent.indexOf('MSIE')>=0?true:false;
var navigatorVersion = navigator.appVersion.replace(/.*?MSIE (\d\.\d).*/g,'$1')/1;


var indicateDestinationBox = false;
function getTopPos(inputObj)
{
  var returnValue = inputObj.offsetTop;
  while((inputObj = inputObj.offsetParent) != null){
   if(inputObj.tagName!='HTML')returnValue += inputObj.offsetTop;
  }
  return returnValue;
}

function getLeftPos(inputObj)
{
  var returnValue = inputObj.offsetLeft;
  while((inputObj = inputObj.offsetParent) != null){
   if(inputObj.tagName!='HTML')returnValue += inputObj.offsetLeft;
  }
  return returnValue;
}

function cancelEvent()
{
 return false;
}
function initDrag(e) // Mouse button is pressed down on a LI
{
 if(document.all)e = event;
 var st = Math.max(document.body.scrollTop,document.documentElement.scrollTop);
 var sl = Math.max(document.body.scrollLeft,document.documentElement.scrollLeft);

 dragTimer = 0;
 dragContentObj.style.left = e.clientX + sl + 'px';
 dragContentObj.style.top = e.clientY + st + 'px';
 contentToBeDragged = this;
 contentToBeDragged_src = this.parentNode;
 contentToBeDragged_next = false;
 if(this.nextSibling){
  contentToBeDragged_next = this.nextSibling;
  if(!this.tagName && contentToBeDragged_next.nextSibling)contentToBeDragged_next = contentToBeDragged_next.nextSibling;
 }
 timerDrag();
 return false;
}

function timerDrag()
{
 if(dragTimer>=0 && dragTimer<10){
  dragTimer++;
  setTimeout('timerDrag()',10);
  return;
 }
 if(dragTimer==10){

  if(cloneSourceItems && contentToBeDragged.parentNode.id=='allItems'){
   newItem = contentToBeDragged.cloneNode(true);
   newItem.onmousedown = contentToBeDragged.onmousedown;
   contentToBeDragged = newItem;
  }
  dragContentObj.style.display='block';
  dragContentObj.appendChild(contentToBeDragged);
 }
}

function moveDragContent(e)
{
 if(dragTimer<10){
  if(contentToBeDragged){
   if(contentToBeDragged_next){
    contentToBeDragged_src.insertBefore(contentToBeDragged,contentToBeDragged_next);
   }else{
    contentToBeDragged_src.appendChild(contentToBeDragged);
   }
  }
  return;
 }
 if(document.all)e = event;
 var st = Math.max(document.body.scrollTop,document.documentElement.scrollTop);
 var sl = Math.max(document.body.scrollLeft,document.documentElement.scrollLeft);


 dragContentObj.style.left = e.clientX + sl + 'px';
 dragContentObj.style.top = e.clientY + st + 'px';

 if(mouseoverObj)mouseoverObj.className='';
 destinationObj = false;
 dragDropIndicator.style.display='none';
 if(indicateDestinationBox)indicateDestinationBox.style.display='none';
 var x = e.clientX + sl;
 var y = e.clientY + st;
 var width = dragContentObj.offsetWidth;
 var height = dragContentObj.offsetHeight;

 var tmpOffsetX = arrow_offsetX;
 var tmpOffsetY = arrow_offsetY;
 if(!document.all){
  tmpOffsetX = arrow_offsetX_firefox;
  tmpOffsetY = arrow_offsetY_firefox;
 }

 for(var no=0;no<ulPositionArray.length;no++){
  var ul_leftPos = ulPositionArray[no]['left'];
  var ul_topPos = ulPositionArray[no]['top'];
  var ul_height = ulPositionArray[no]['height'];
  var ul_width = ulPositionArray[no]['width'];

  if((x+width) > ul_leftPos && x<(ul_leftPos + ul_width) && (y+height)> ul_topPos && y<(ul_topPos + ul_height)){
   var noExisting = ulPositionArray[no]['obj'].getElementsByTagName('LI').length;
   if(indicateDestinationBox && indicateDestinationBox.parentNode==ulPositionArray[no]['obj'])noExisting--;
   if(noExisting<boxSizeArray[no-1] || no==0){
    dragDropIndicator.style.left = ul_leftPos + tmpOffsetX + 'px';
    var subLi = ulPositionArray[no]['obj'].getElementsByTagName('LI');

    var clonedItemAllreadyAdded = false;
    if(cloneSourceItems && !cloneAllowDuplicates){
     for(var liIndex=0;liIndex<subLi.length;liIndex++){
      if(contentToBeDragged.id == subLi[liIndex].id)clonedItemAllreadyAdded = true;
     }
     if(clonedItemAllreadyAdded)continue;
    }

    for(var liIndex=0;liIndex<subLi.length;liIndex++){
     var tmpTop = getTopPos(subLi[liIndex]);
     if(!indicateDestionationByUseOfArrow){
      if(y<tmpTop){
       destinationObj = subLi[liIndex];
       indicateDestinationBox.style.display='block';
       subLi[liIndex].parentNode.insertBefore(indicateDestinationBox,subLi[liIndex]);
       break;
      }
     }else{
      if(y<tmpTop){
       destinationObj = subLi[liIndex];
       dragDropIndicator.style.top = tmpTop + tmpOffsetY - Math.round(dragDropIndicator.clientHeight/2) + 'px';
       dragDropIndicator.style.display='block';
       break;
      }
     }
    }

    if(!indicateDestionationByUseOfArrow){
     if(indicateDestinationBox.style.display=='none'){
      indicateDestinationBox.style.display='block';
      ulPositionArray[no]['obj'].appendChild(indicateDestinationBox);
     }

    }else{
     if(subLi.length>0 && dragDropIndicator.style.display=='none'){
      dragDropIndicator.style.top = getTopPos(subLi[subLi.length-1]) + subLi[subLi.length-1].offsetHeight + tmpOffsetY + 'px';
      dragDropIndicator.style.display='block';
     }
     if(subLi.length==0){
      dragDropIndicator.style.top = ul_topPos + arrow_offsetY + 'px'
      dragDropIndicator.style.display='block';
     }
    }

    if(!destinationObj)destinationObj = ulPositionArray[no]['obj'];
    mouseoverObj = ulPositionArray[no]['obj'].parentNode;
    mouseoverObj.className='mouseover';
    return;
   }
  }
 }
}

/* End dragging
Put <LI> into a destination or back to where it came from.
*/
function dragDropEnd(e)
{
 if(dragTimer==-1)return;
 if(dragTimer<10){
  dragTimer = -1;
  return;
 }
 dragTimer = -1;
 if(document.all)e = event;


 if(cloneSourceItems && (!destinationObj || (destinationObj && (destinationObj.id=='allItems' || destinationObj.parentNode.id=='allItems')))){
  contentToBeDragged.parentNode.removeChild(contentToBeDragged);
 }else{

  if(destinationObj){
   if(destinationObj.tagName=='UL'){
    destinationObj.appendChild(contentToBeDragged);
   }else{
    destinationObj.parentNode.insertBefore(contentToBeDragged,destinationObj);
   }
   mouseoverObj.className='';
   destinationObj = false;
   dragDropIndicator.style.display='none';
   if(indicateDestinationBox){
    indicateDestinationBox.style.display='none';
    document.body.appendChild(indicateDestinationBox);
   }
   contentToBeDragged = false;
   return;
  }
  if(contentToBeDragged_next){
   contentToBeDragged_src.insertBefore(contentToBeDragged,contentToBeDragged_next);
  }else{
   contentToBeDragged_src.appendChild(contentToBeDragged);
  }
 }
 contentToBeDragged = false;
 dragDropIndicator.style.display='none';
 if(indicateDestinationBox){
  indicateDestinationBox.style.display='none';
  document.body.appendChild(indicateDestinationBox);

 }
 mouseoverObj = false;

}

/*
Preparing data to be saved
*/
function saveDragDropNodes()
{
 var saveString = "";
 var uls = dragDropTopContainer.getElementsByTagName('UL');
 for(var no=0;no<uls.length;no++){ // LOoping through all <ul>
  var lis = uls[no].getElementsByTagName('LI');
  for(var no2=0;no2<lis.length;no2++){
   if(saveString.length>0)saveString = saveString + ";";
   saveString = saveString + uls[no].id + '|' + lis[no2].id;
  }
 }

 document.getElementById('saveContent').innerHTML = '<h1>Ready to save these nodes:</h1> ' + saveString.replace(/;/g,';<br>') + '<p>Format: ID of ul |(pipe) ID of li;(semicolon)</p><p>You can put these values into a hidden form fields, post it to the server and explode the submitted value there</p>';

}

function initDragDropScript()
{
 dragContentObj = document.getElementById('dragContent');
 dragDropIndicator = document.getElementById('dragDropIndicator');
 dragDropTopContainer = document.getElementById('dhtmlgoodies_dragDropContainer');
 document.documentElement.onselectstart = cancelEvent;;
 var listItems = dragDropTopContainer.getElementsByTagName('LI'); // Get array containing all <LI>
 var itemHeight = false;
 for(var no=0;no<listItems.length;no++){
  listItems[no].onmousedown = initDrag;
  listItems[no].onselectstart = cancelEvent;
  if(!itemHeight)itemHeight = listItems[no].offsetHeight;
  if(MSIE && navigatorVersion/1<6){
   listItems[no].style.cursor='hand';
  }
 }

 var mainContainer = document.getElementById('dhtmlgoodies_mainContainer');
 var uls = mainContainer.getElementsByTagName('UL');
 itemHeight = itemHeight + verticalSpaceBetweenListItems;
 for(var no=0;no<uls.length;no++){
  uls[no].style.height = itemHeight * boxSizeArray[no]  + 'px';
 }

 var leftContainer = document.getElementById('dhtmlgoodies_listOfItems');
 var itemBox = leftContainer.getElementsByTagName('UL')[0];

 document.documentElement.onmousemove = moveDragContent; // Mouse move event - moving draggable div
 document.documentElement.onmouseup = dragDropEnd; // Mouse move event - moving draggable div

 var ulArray = dragDropTopContainer.getElementsByTagName('UL');
 for(var no=0;no<ulArray.length;no++){
  ulPositionArray[no] = new Array();
  ulPositionArray[no]['left'] = getLeftPos(ulArray[no]);
  ulPositionArray[no]['top'] = getTopPos(ulArray[no]);
  ulPositionArray[no]['width'] = ulArray[no].offsetWidth;
  ulPositionArray[no]['height'] = ulArray[no].clientHeight;
  ulPositionArray[no]['obj'] = ulArray[no];
 }

 if(!indicateDestionationByUseOfArrow){
  indicateDestinationBox = document.createElement('LI');
  indicateDestinationBox.id = 'indicateDestination';
  indicateDestinationBox.style.display='none';
  document.body.appendChild(indicateDestinationBox);


 }
}

window.onload = initDragDropScript;
```

```css
body{
 font-family: Trebuchet MS, Lucida Sans Unicode, Arial, sans-serif; /* Font to use */
 background-color:#E2EBED;
}
#footer{
 height:30px;
 vertical-align:middle;
 text-align:right;
 clear:both;
 padding-right:3px;
 background-color:#317082;
 margin-top:2px;
 width:1250px;
}
#footer form{
 margin:0px;
 margin-top:2px;
}
#dhtmlgoodies_dragDropContainer{ /* Main container for this script */
 width:100%;
 height:2250px;
 border:1px solid #317082;
 background-color:#FFF;
 -moz-user-select:none;
}
#dhtmlgoodies_dragDropContainer ul{ /* General rules for all <ul> */
 margin-top:0px;
 margin-left:0px;
 margin-bottom:0px;
 padding:2px;
}

#dhtmlgoodies_dragDropContainer li,#dragContent li,li#indicateDestination{ /* Movable items, i.e. <LI> */
 list-style-type:none;
 height:20px;
 background-color:#EEE;
 border:1px solid #000;
 padding:2px;
 margin-bottom:2px;
 cursor:pointer;
 font-size:0.9em;
}

li#indicateDestination{ /* Box indicating where content will be dropped - i.e. the one you use if you don't use arrow */
 border:1px dotted #600;
 background-color:#FFF;
}


/* LEFT COLUMN CSS */
div#dhtmlgoodies_listOfItems{ /* Left column "Available students" */

 float:left;
 padding-left:10px;
 padding-right:10px;

 /* CSS HACK */
 width: 180px; /* IE 5.x */
 width/* */:/**/160px; /* Other browsers */
 width: /**/160px;

}
#dhtmlgoodies_listOfItems ul{ /* Left(Sources) column <ul> */
 height:2184px;

}

div#dhtmlgoodies_listOfItems div{
 border:1px solid #999;
}
div#dhtmlgoodies_listOfItems div ul{ /* Left column <ul> */
 margin-left:10px; /* Space at the left of list - the arrow will be positioned there */
}
#dhtmlgoodies_listOfItems div p{ /* Heading above left column */
 margin:0px;
 font-weight:bold;
 padding-left:12px;
 background-color:#317082;
 color:#FFF;
 margin-bottom:5px;
}
/* END LEFT COLUMN CSS */

#dhtmlgoodies_dragDropContainer .mouseover{ /* Mouse over effect DIV box in right column */
 background-color:#E2EBED;
 border:1px solid #317082;
}

/* Start main container CSS */

div#dhtmlgoodies_mainContainer{ /* Right column DIV */
 width:1096px;
 float:left;
}
#dhtmlgoodies_mainContainer div{ /* Parent <div> of small boxes */
 float:left;
 margin-right:10px;
 margin-bottom:10px;
 margin-top:0px;
 border:1px solid #999;

 /* CSS HACK */
 width: 172px; /* IE 5.x */
 width/* */:/**/170px; /* Other browsers */
 width: /**/170px;

}
#dhtmlgoodies_mainContainer div ul{
 margin-left:10px;
}

#dhtmlgoodies_mainContainer div p{ /* Heading above small boxes */
 margin:0px;
 padding:0px;
 padding-left:12px;
 font-weight:bold;
 background-color:#317082;
 color:#FFF;
 margin-bottom:5px;
}

#dhtmlgoodies_mainContainer ul{ /* Small box in right column ,i.e <ul> */
 width:152px;
 height:80px;
 border:0px;
 margin-bottom:0px;
 overflow:hidden;

}

#dragContent{ /* Drag container */
 position:absolute;
 width:150px;
 height:20px;
 display:none;
 margin:0px;
 padding:0px;
 z-index:2000;
}

#dragDropIndicator{ /* DIV for the small arrow */
 position:absolute;
 width:7px;
 height:10px;
 display:none;
 z-index:1000;
 margin:0px;
 padding:0px;
}
</style>
<style type="text/css" media="print">
div#dhtmlgoodies_listOfItems{
 display:none;
}
body{
 background-color:#FFF;
}
img{
 display:none;
}
#dhtmlgoodies_dragDropContainer{
 border:0px;
 width:100%;
}
p{
 margin-bottom:0px;
}
```

```html
    <div id="dhtmlgoodies_dragDropContainer">
        <div id="topBar">
            <img src="/images/heading3.gif" />
        </div>
        <div id="dhtmlgoodies_listOfItems">
            <div>
                <p>
                    Available players
                </p>
                <ul id="allItems">
                    <li id="node7">Player A
                    </li>
                    <li id="node8">Player B
                    </li>
                    <li id="node9">Player C
                    </li>
                    <li id="node10">Player D
                    </li>
                    <li id="node11">Player E
                    </li>
                    <li id="node12">Player F
                    </li>
                    <li id="node13">Player G
                    </li>
                    <li id="node14">Player H
                    </li>
                    <li id="node15">Player I
                    </li>
                    <li id="node16">Player J
                    </li>
                    <li id="node17">Player K
                    </li>
                    <li id="node18">Player L
                    </li>
                    <li id="node19">Player M
                    </li>
                    <li id="node20">Player N
                    </li>
                    <li id="node21">Player O
                    </li>
                    <li id="node22">Player P
                    </li>
                    <li id="node23">Player Q
                    </li>
                    <li id="node24">Player R
                    </li>
                    <li id="node25">Player S
                    </li>
                    <li id="node26">Player T
                    </li>
                    <li id="node27">Player U
                    </li>
                    <li id="node28">Player V
                    </li>
                    <li id="node29">Player W
                    </li>
                    <li id="node30">Player X
                    </li>
                    <li id="node31">Player Y
                    </li>
                    <li id="node32">Player Z
                    </li>
                    <li id="node33">Player AA
                    </li>
                    <li id="node34">Player AB
                    </li>
                    <li id="node35">Player AC
                    </li>
                    <li id="node36">Player AD
                    </li>
                    <li id="node37">Player AE
                    </li>
                    <li id="node38">Player AF
                    </li>
                    <li id="node39">Player AG
                    </li>
                    <li id="node40">Player AH
                    </li>
                    <li id="node41">Player AI
                    </li>
                    <li id="node42">Player AJ
                    </li>
                    <li id="node43">Player AK
                    </li>
                    <li id="node44">Player AL
                    </li>
                    <li id="node45">Player AM
                    </li>
                    <li id="node46">Player AN
                    </li>
                    <li id="node47">Player AO
                    </li>
                    <li id="node48">Player AP
                    </li>
                    <li id="node49">Player AQ
                    </li>
                    <li id="node50">Player AR
                    </li>
                    <li id="node51">Player AS
                    </li>
                    <li id="node52">Player AT
                    </li>
                    <li id="node53">Player AU
                    </li>
                    <li id="node54">Player AV
                    </li>
                    <li id="node55">Player AW
                    </li>
                    <li id="node56">Player AX
                    </li>
                    <li id="node57">Player AY
                    </li>
                    <li id="node58">Player AZ
                    </li>
                    <li id="node59">Player BA
                    </li>
                    <li id="node60">Player BB
                    </li>
                    <li id="node61">Player BC
                    </li>
                    <li id="node62">Player BD
                    </li>
                    <li id="node63">Player BE
                    </li>
                    <li id="node64">Player BF
                    </li>
                    <li id="node65">Player BG
                    </li>
                    <li id="node66">Player BH
                    </li>
                    <li id="node67">Player BI
                    </li>
                    <li id="node68">Player BJ
                    </li>
                    <li id="node69">Player BK
                    </li>
                    <li id="node70">Player BL
                    </li>
                    <li id="node71">Player BM
                    </li>
                    <li id="node72">Player BN
                    </li>
                    <li id="node73">Player BO
                    </li>
                    <li id="node74">Player BP
                    </li>
                    <li id="node75">Player BQ
                    </li>
                    <li id="node76">Player BR
                    </li>
                    <li id="node77">Player BS
                    </li>
                    <li id="node78">Player BT
                    </li>
                    <li id="node79">Player BU
                    </li>
                    <li id="node80">Player BV
                    </li>
                    <li id="node81">Player BW
                    </li>
                    <li id="node82">Player BX
                    </li>
                    <li id="node83">Player BY
                    </li>
                    <li id="node84">Player BZ
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div id="dhtmlgoodies_mainContainer">
            <!-- ONE <UL> for each "room" -->
            <div>
                <p>
                    Team A
                </p>
                <ul id="box1">
                    <li id="node1">Captain A
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </div>
            <div>
                <p>
                    Team B
                </p>
                <ul id="box2">
                    <li id="node2">Captain B
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </div>
            <div>
                <p>
                    Team C
                </p>
                <ul id="box3">
                    <li id="node3">Captain C
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </div>
            <div>
                <p>
                    Team D
                </p>
                <ul id="box4">
                    <li id="node4">Captain D
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </div>
            <div>
                <p>
                    Team E
                </p>
                <ul id="box5">
                    <li id="node5">Captain E
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </div>
            <div>
                <p>
                    Team F
                </p>
                <ul id="box6">
                    <li id="node6">Captain F
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div id="footer">
        <form action="aPage.html" method="post">
            <input type="button" onclick="saveDragDropNodes()" value="Save" />
        </form>
    </div>
    <ul id="dragContent"></ul>
    <div id="dragDropIndicator">
        <img src="images/insert.gif" />
    </div>
    <div id="saveContent"></div>
```

Comment: PLEASE DO NOT PASTE YOUR WHOLE PROJECT.

Answer (score 1):

You can easily use "Web SQL" to deal with this case

this a small introduction about usage of "Web SQL"

```
var db = openDatabase('mydb', '1.0', 'my first database', 2 * 1024 * 1024);
db.transaction(function(tx) {
    tx.executeSql('CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS players (id unique, text)');
    tx.executeSql('INSERT INTO players (id, text) VALUES (1, "A")');
    tx.executeSql('SELECT * FROM players', [], function(tx, results) {
        var len = results.rows.length;
        for (var i = 0; i < len; i++) {
            alert(results.rows.item(i).text);
        }
    });
});
```

Very good tutorial about "Web SQL" from [HERE](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/html5/html5_web_sql.htm)

Comment: This works fine for Chrome, Safari, & Opera... But something that can work in Firefox?